# jQuery facebook like popbox top navigation

Tags: html, css, facebook, jquery

i just want to make facebook like popbox top navigation as below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQqJi.png

the problem is, how to toggle another popbox named POPBOX2 with btn2, POPBOX3 with btn3 and so on. The **LAYOUT** of **popBox2** and **popBox3** same as **popBox1**, but the **arrow** of the popBox is under the btn. How to do this? i've copied my problem at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/FArIZzX77/dNVUj/

thanks for the answer :)

Comment: have you tried anything yet? (Thanks for posting that jsFiddle, I always wanted to know how that was done! I'm still struggling with how the top arrows is made.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [facebook like top navigation css & jquery](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/12595567/facebook-like-top-navigation-css-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, like this. Wrapped inside jQuery document.ready.

**Button that opens the popup-box**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#linkid').click(function(){
        $('.popupboxclass').hide();
        $('#popupbox1').show();
    });
    $('#link2id').click(function(){
        $('.popupboxclass').hide();
        $('#popupbox2').show();
    });
    $('#link3id').click(function(){
        $('.popupboxclass').hide();
        $('#popupbox3').show();
    });
});​
```

**CSS:**

```
.yourcontainer{
position:relative;
}

.popupboxclass{
display:none;
position:absolute;
top:50px;
left;50px;
width:200px;
height:200px;
border:1px solid #000;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="yourcontainer">
    <a href="#" id="linkid">Open popup 1</a>
    <a href="#" id="link2id">Open popup 2</a>
    <a href="#" id="link3id">Open popup 3</a>
    <div class="popupboxclass" id="popupbox1">Box 1</div>
    <div class="popupboxclass" id="popupbox2">Box 2</div>
    <div class="popupboxclass" id="popupbox3">Box 3</div>
</div>​
```

And a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sqa2D/1/

**But please, try something before asking. Don't just sit and wait and think that the community will do it for you. This is the simplest thing you can do with jQuery.**

**EDIT**
I misunderstood a part, I edited my answer.

Comment: So basically, you assign the desired popupbox a class ``popupboxclass` and an id depending on the number of the box, like `popupbox1`, `popupbox2` etc.

Answer (score 0):

See This **[EDIT FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/c9fyY/)** put every `popbox` separate.

Comment: Why use a plugin? You can just do it with few lines and keep it lighter.